# How to display a loading indicator in FullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullcalendar, loading

I'm incorporating [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io) into my website right now and I'm trying to add a loading indicator that shows while the calendar is fetching events from the server. I understand how to use the "loading" function provided by FullCalendar to show and hide the loading indicator. What I don't know how to do is show the loading indicator over the top of the contents of the calendar.

For example, in this image I would like to show the loading indicator where the list of events is (inside the grey box) when the list is being reloaded.

[image: FullCalendar Example]